# Esperar respuesta del Servidor en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero que mi `<script>` no se se siga ejecutando hasta tener la respuesta del servidor y hacer lo que tiene que hacer, estoy usando Javascript nativo del navegador, es decir, sin frameworks ni librerías ni nada.

```
<script>
        function run(){
             cargar() 
             sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant);
        } 
        </script>
    </head>
     <body class="spp-loading" onload="run()">
```

Aquí en el Head, creo la función cargar(); CUANDO haya terminado esa función quiero que se ejecute la siguiente línea.

```
function cargar() {

// realizamos proceso de validacion del JSON
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "./entrada", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        var MyJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        procesar(MyJSON);
    }
  }
}
```

A su vez esta función llamará a otras y así, pero cuando termine el Cargar(); es cuando el código javascript debe seguir, ¿ cómo hago esto ?

De momento el JSON del servidor, lo cojo del local, en un futuro, se llamará a un servidor...

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que AJAX su funcionalidad es asíncrona, es decir, el script de JS seguirá corriendo sin importar si ya te respondió o no. Aquí podemos hacer dos cosas en tu función cargar

```
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    var MyJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant);
    procesar(MyJSON);
}
```

Lanzar tu función `sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant);` Cuando el servidor responda, o

```
request.open("GET", "./entrada", false);
```

Cambiar la petición a síncrona, es decir, no continuar con el script hasta que el servidor responda.

Para lo que requieres, te serviría mejor poner síncrona la petición ya que si tienes más código en tu JS lo tendrás que meter al if del success del AJAX

Comment: El problema es que  sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant); debe ir cuando termine el procesar.

Comment: Por eso, las dos opciones te sirven.

Comment: Perdona mi desconocimiento, pero no entiendo como me puede ayudar eso, si estás diciendo que sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant); se ejecute antes de procesar(MyJson);

Comment: procesar(MyJSON); creará los elementos que .init(optionsAssistant); utilizará después, pero lo estás poniendo una línea antes.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: optionsAssistant is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange

Comment: Pues entonces baja esa línea y ya, ahora, tu función procesar() que hace? Va de nuevo al servidor?

Comment: Creo que te sirve mejor si pones tu función síncrona, cambia el true por false en el .open()

Comment: Perdona, a veces soy bastante cerrado de mente... puse la línea debajo, y funciona perfectamente !! (L)

Comment: Id borrando los comentarios que no sean utiles u obsoletos. Para mantener limpia la publicacion. Si necesitais un chat, avisad. Un saludo

Comment: Recuerda marcar como correcta la respuesta, para que otros users con problemas similares tengan esto como base, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que quieres hacer lo puedes hacer con un *`callback`*, un callback garantiza que cierto código no se ejecute hasta que otro fragmento haya terminado su ejecución. La implementación es algo así:

```
function primera(callback) {
  // Simular un retraso en el código
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(1);
    callback();
  }, 500);
}
function segunda() {
  console.log(2);
}

primera(segunda);
```

Para tu ejemplo se podría realizar así. La función `cargar()` quedaría:

```
function cargar(callback) {

  // realizamos proceso de validacion del JSON
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "./entrada", true);
  request.send(null);
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      var MyJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      procesar(MyJSON);
      callback();
    }
  }
}
```

Y para llamarla sería algo así:

```
function run() {
  cargar(function () { 
    // Aqui va el código que quieres ejecutar cuando termine la función cargar()
    sppWizard.init(optionsAssistant);
  })

}
```